# issue with Connecting Vitess from mysql Work Bench

Tags: vitess, kubernetes-vitess

we are able to connect Vitess from dot net core application but where as we are getting attached error while connecting vitess from MySQL Work bench.

is anything we are missing.

[image: MYSQL Work Bench connection issue]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good number of workbench issues have been fixed. We're now working on handling the SET statements that it sends. Hopefully, that should cover most use cases. Until then, the workaround is to configure workbench to not send these preamble queries.

Comment: How do we turn off the preamble queries?

Comment: We've come a long way since I posted this. Things should just work now. If now, feel free to file an issue,

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102959 ...Here's hoping!

Comment: @akenney looks like there was a regression. A bug has been filed https://github.com/vitessio/vitess/issues/7697